# How to extract all row values under all columns of a Dataframe and transfer them into an empty 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, multidimensional-array

I have created a Dataframe from a multilabel classification form.

[image: Dataframe]

My only concern is on **how to extract all row values under a column of my dataframe**, then transfer them to an **empty 2D numpy array?** Specifically I want all the row values under all columns of my dataframe.

The **goal output** should look like this:

[image: Goal Output]

The problem is that I am not sure how to properly transfer them in a correct way.

Full [Google Colab source code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QvSwpgd_-vwlKc2OKCDVKgXwd1aQnJJZ?usp=sharing):

My attempt:

```
import sys
import sklearn
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification as mmc

X, Y, p_c, p_w_c = mmc(
    n_samples = 5,
    n_features = 4,
    n_classes = 3,
    n_labels = 4,
    length = 25000, 
    allow_unlabeled = True,
    return_distributions = True,
    random_state = 1
)

#produced dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((X, Y)))

#empty 2D array
new_df_array = np.array([[]])

#iterate to each columns and append all its row values into an empty 2D array (but this doesn't work)
for index in df.columns.to_list():
    result = np.append(new_df_array, df[index].values)
```

Thus, the output is:

```
array([0., 1., 0., 0., 1.])
```

This is not what I'm looking for.

I would definitely need some of your help and guidance in order to properly implement the extraction of all the row values of my dataframe. Your responses would indeed help me a lot.

Comment: Maybe `df.to_numpy()` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Using that will result into including row values from other columns instead of extracting first the row values under a current column being iterated before going to another column to extract the row values under that column. Thus, this results to a different output compared to my goal output above.

Comment: `df.T.to_numpy()`, transposing the `df` first (`.T`)?

Comment: Simply use `new_df_array = df.values.T`.

Comment: @ouroboros1
Exactly what I'm looking for! Both ways results to my goal output.
Thank you very much for the responses! It indeed helped me a lot!

Comment: @Corralien Your way also still results to my goal output! Thank you very much for the responses! It indeed helped me a lot!